# C - how to get rid of memory leaks?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, singly-linked-list

How can I get rid of memory leaks from for example this function:

```
void AddData(Data **head, char *sentence, int number) {
    Words *words = NULL;
    char delimiters[] = " \n\0";
    char *token = strtok(sentence, delimiters);
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (IsAlphabetical(token) == 1) {
            char *string = (char *)malloc((strlen(token) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(string, token);
            AddWords(&words, string);
            free(string);
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiters);
    }

    Data *temp = *head;
    Data *newData = (Data *)malloc(sizeof(Data));

    newData->lineNumber = number;
    newData->words = words;
    newData->pNext = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = newData;
    else {
        while (temp->pNext != NULL)
            temp = temp->pNext;

        temp->pNext = newData;
    }
}
```

---

My personal opinion is the leaks appear because of `newData`, `temp` and `words` variables.

I have a few similar functions that cause the same problem.
I have also function for deleting Data struct, but when I call it at the end of previous function in such way `DeleteData(&temp)` program will not execute. I think it's because my whole list is deleted.

```
void DeleteData(Data **head) {
    Data *temp = *head;
    while (temp->pNext != NULL) {
        Data *next = temp->pNext;
        DeleteWords(&temp->words);
        free(temp);
        temp = next;
    }
    free(temp); /* to check that */
    *head = NULL;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does the absent routine `AddWords()` allocate anything and if so, are those allocs ever freed?  Are the allocs initially assigned to `newData` being freed?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre], including input data, observed behavior of the program, desired behavior, and the evidence you have that there are leaks.

Comment: You don’t allocate anything to `temp` so nothing can leak. Have you run the code through valgrind or other such tool that would tell you if there’s leaks? But since this is only partial code it’s impossible to say about everything

Comment: Is it good idea to post all my code? It's about 600 lines

Comment: I run using drmemeory

Answer (score 0):

Here are some problems I identified:

- The trailing `\0` in `char delimiters[] = " \n\0";` is useless.
- Testing `if (IsAlphabetical(token) == 1)` might be too restrictive. In C anything non 0 is true so you might test `if (IsAlphabetical(token) != 0)` or just `if (IsAlphabetical(token))`.
- Why allocate a copy of the string to pass to `AddWords(&words, string);` and then `free(string)` thereafter? If `Addwords()` does not keep the pointer it gets, there is no need to allocate a copy.
- Does `AddWords()` call `strtok()`? `strtok()` is non-reentrant, which means that if `AddWords()` or any other function called in this loop, such as `IsAlphabetical()` calls `strtok()`, the context used in the loop will be corrupted. You should use `strtok_r()` instead.
- in function `DeleteData`, why do you iterate testing `while (temp->pNext != NULL)`? The last item in the list does not get freed properly, the `DeleteWords(&temp->words);` is not called. **This may cause a memory leak**. You should just write:

  ```
    void DeleteData(Data **head) {
        Data *temp = *head;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            Data *next = temp->pNext;
            DeleteWords(&temp->words);
            free(temp);
            temp = next;
        }
        *head = NULL;
    }
  ```

Comment: Could we go on any kind of chat? Like messenger or something? It's bigger thing :/

Comment: @Cris: Sorry but not right now, I have to do some errance. Post comments and I shall try and address other *bigger* issues.

Comment: I will post an answer below, because i want to share part of my code, let me sec

Comment: Answer is above

Comment: @Cris: in `AddWords` you must test `temp->pNext != NULL` in the loop to locate the last node in the list. If you just test `temp != NULL`, `temp` will be `NULL` after the loop. Conversely, in `DeleteData`, you must free **every** node so you must iterate until `temp` is `NULL`.

Comment: @Cris: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.